# Django-admin is not working Django 1.11 Python 3.6

Tags: python, django, windows-7

I tried to research on all related topics here and googled it but the django-admin command is not doing anything whenever I type it in CMD (win 7).

It only opens my pycharm and shows codes inside the django-admin.py. I already added it to environment variables and tried these syntax but didn't work (I was able to create and run virtual environment):

version1:
`django-admin startproject mysite`

version2:
`django-admin.py startproject mysite`

version3:
`path-to-django-admin\django-admin.py startproject mysite`

I even tried to copy the django-admin.py on my project folder but didn't do any good.

Comment: try this with a new virtualenv then activating it and then install django and check if you can create a project or not

Comment: @Exprator. I tried what you said. I installed Django while inside virtualenv and did "django-admin --version", it works fine but when I did the code: "django-admin startproject mysite ." (The period is included) and it worked. Finally the manage.py file showed up thqt I can use inside the pycharm project

Comment: Great. Pleasure that could help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exprator's answer worked for me. I installed Django while inside virtualenv and did "django-admin --version", it works fine then I did the code: "django-admin startproject mysite ." (The period is included) and it worked. Finally the manage.py showed up inside the project folder.

Answer (score 0):

in windows inside a virtual environment you need to invoke the Python interpreter with django-admin.py:

```
python django-admin.py startproject mysite
```

Comment: thanks but it gave me an error that no django-admin folder found

Comment: are you inside an active virtual environment? did yo type the .py at the end of django-admin?

Comment: yes I am, so what I did is to reinstall the Django framework while I'm inside the virtual environment and for some reason everything started to work :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using virtualenv with python3, you may want to try out the following:

```
(virtualenv) $> python3 -m django [subcommand]
```

- Note Django version under test is 2.2.3